# How do I wire up this transmitter and camera

Tags: video-transmitters, fpv-cameras

I'm a total newbie to FPV and electronics. My son bought the following components as an adventure into FPV for his Remote Control vehicles (cars, planes, drones).
[image: Picture of the bits and pieces]

Descriptions of the components:

**Eachine TX805 5.8G 40CH 25/200/600/800mW FPV Transmitter TX** LED Display Support OSD/Pitmode/Smart Audio
https://www.banggood.com/Eachine-TX805-5_8G-40CH-25-or-200-or-600-or-800mW-FPV-Transmitter-TX-LED-Display-Support-OSD-or-Pitmode-or-Smart-Audio-p-1333984.html

**RunCam Swift 2 600TVL 1/3 CCD** 2.5mm/2.3mm/2.1mm FOV 130/150/165 Degree Mini FPV Camera PAL with MIC Support OSD
https://www.banggood.com/RunCam-Swift-2-600TVL-1-or-3-CCD-2_5mm-or-2_3mm-or-2_1mm-FOV-130-or-150-or-165-Degree-Mini-FPV-Camera-PAL-with-MIC-Support-OSD-p-1118948.html

**Eachine ROTG02 UVC OTG 5.8G 150CH Diversity Audio FPV Receiver** for Android Tablet Smartphone
https://www.banggood.com/Eachine-ROTG02-UVC-OTG-5_8G-150CH-Diversity-Audio-FPV-Receiver-for-Android-Tablet-Smartphone-p-1242422.html

The transmitter says it takes between 7 and 24V - so the first issue is to find a battery to power this that fits the connector it has. I don't know how to describe the connector it has so I don't know how to find a compatible battery.

Second, from what I understand the transmitter has 5V out to power the camera, but I don't know how I'm supposed to attach the 2 together.

My first objective is to get the transmitter and camera connected, with a battery to power the transmitter - so we can at least get something working. Can anyone help me understand what I need to do?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hey prule! There's going to be a fair amount of soldering wires together involved here, are you familiar with how to do cut/splice wires together with solder and an iron?

Comment: I should be okay with soldering. Used to do it as a kid, I'm sure I'll figure it out IF I know what I'm soldering to what... thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These components can be split into two functional groups, one for transmitting a picture and one for receiving it, which aren't connected to one another by wires. The Runcam camera and Eachine VTX are both parts of the transmitting section, while the receiver doesn't need to be soldered to anything else in the receiving part.

#### Required Soldered Connections:

You'll need to make the following wire connections between the different components: (*splicing together the components' connector pigtails is recommended as opposed to trying to solder directly to the camera*)

- `Battery+` → VTX `7-24V` wire
- `Battery-` → VTX `GND` wire (*there are a total of two available, choose either one*)
- `Battery+` or VTX `+5V` wire → Runcam `5-36V` wire
- `Battery-` or VTX `GND` wire → Runcam `GND` wire (*in 5-pin camera connector, not the 2-pin camera controller connector*)
- Runcam `Video` wire → VTX `VIDEO` wire

Essentially, both the camera and VTX need to be connected to each other for the analog video signal (*one wire*) and each need to have connections to ground/`GND` and a positive voltage source within their requirements.

#### Battery Setup:

In this setup, the VTX is actually the component that constrains the kind of power sources/batteries you can use. It requires 7-24V to operate, which means you can use 2S-5S LiPo batteries with it. (*or another battery pack within the same voltage range*)

Most drone/RC LiPo batteries these days come with either an XT30 or XT60 connector, but can be purchased with other terminations. See this page for [a list of the most common ones](https://blog.ampow.com/rc-battery-connector-types/#:%7E:text=%20Medium%20RC%20LiPo%20Connectors%20%2830-70%20Amps%29%20,RC%20battery%20connector%20type%20best%20among...%20More%20). Once you know what your battery's connector is called, you can purchase a set of connectors online and solder them to the VTX and camera as required.

It's unlikely you'll be able to match the connectors that come with the parts together. While the connectors are all off-the-shelf parts, their usage is unfortunately not really that standardized between manufacturers. You're probably better off just cutting the cable that came with the camera in half and soldering it together with the pigtail wires that come with the VTX.

Once this is done, you can hopefully power on the VTX, camera, and receiver without issues, (*remember to screw on the VTX's antenna before powering up so you don't damage it!!!*) set the VTX and receiver to the same channel, and view the picture on the connected Android phone/tablet.

*Did I leave something out? Please let me know if I did and something doesn't make sense...*

Comment: Thanks for such good answer. It'll take me some time to work through it, but when I do I'll let you know. Sounds like it makes good sense so far... Looking forward to figuring this out!